# Paypal Subscription in Android

Tags: android, paypal

I am newbie in android development and I was trying to integrate the pay pal with my android application and I  have done that but now I want to do it as a monthly subscription , which means that when the user sign up for the first time its free to sign up then from the next month he needs to pay first on the pay pal then he can come there . Here is my current code of pay pal payment

```
public class Paypal extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


   // Intent i = new Intent(this, PaypalExpressCheckout.class);
    //this.startActivity(i);
    invokeSimplePayment();
}


//===============================================================
private void invokeSimplePayment(){

    try{

        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.99));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        //.setCurrency("USD");
        newPayment.setRecipient("waleed@balianti.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("balianti");

        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        if(pp==null)
            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

        Intent paypalIntent = pp.checkout(newPayment, this);
        this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

Kindly let me know what I have do .